# Assumptions on proofs

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, relations

I will refer to Exercise 14 of Section 4.6 of Velleman's 2nd edition book. The exercise is as follows:

Suppose $B\subseteq A$ and define a relation $R$ on $\mathscr{P}(A)$ as follows:
$R=\{ (X,Y)\in\mathscr{P}(A)\times\mathscr{P}(A) \; | \; (X\Delta Y) \subseteq B \}$.
Prove that $R$ is an equivalence relation on $\mathscr{P}(A)$.

I know we need to check for reflexiveness, symmetry, and transitivity. I have some questions in the proof for symmetry. So the procedure is quite standard. Suppose $X,Y,Z\in \mathscr{P}(A)$ and let $(X,Y)\in R$ and $(Y,Z)\in R$. Suppose also that $m\in X\Delta Z$ and so we need to show that $m\in B$. From $m\in X\Delta Z$, we know that $m\in X\setminus Z$ or $m\in Z\setminus X$. I know I can use $(X,Y)\in R$ and $(Y,Z)\in R$, but I still need to know if $m\in Y$ so that I can use those assumptions. I noticed that I could just continue with my proof using $m\in Y$ or $m\notin Y$, [as in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3410633/suppose-b-subseteq-a-and-r-x-y-in-mathscr-pa-times-mathscr-pa). My question is, why is it valid to do that in a proof and in which cases can I make use of this resource?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In standard logic, you can use $s \lor (\lnot s)$ for any formula $s$, as a logical axiom or simple theorem. Intuitionist logic doesn't assume or conclude that, but that's a specific context, not the default for most mathematical exercises.

Comment: Got it. Now I recall this idea is similar to the one of proof by contradiction. Thank you very much. If you want to post this as answer, I will give you the "accepted anser" check

Comment: You say you have a question about proving symmetry, but you appear to be talking about a proof of transitivity.